# Push_back shared_ptr of derived class

Tags: c++, containers, shared-ptr

I cannot understand what is going on with my code: why I get a "no matching function for call to push_back" error. I can only guess it is a newby mistake...

```
int main(){
  typedef std::tr1::shared_ptr<Base> Base_p;
  typedef std::vector<Base_p> VectorPointers_t;

  std::tr1::shared_ptr<Derived> myDer01(Derived); 
  VectorPointers_t myVector = VectorPointers_t();
  myVector.push_back(myDer01);  
}
```

Comment: `VectorPointers_t myVector = VectorPointers_t();` isn't what you want, although it probably isn't doing you any harm in this instance http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe you need to downcast you object "myDer01"

Comment: That's not how shared pointers work... they're initialized from a *pointer*.

Comment: @Benj even after I've read the wikipedia link I have troubles figuring out what "VectorPointers_t myVector = VectorPointers_t();" effect is. On the contrary I o understand the same issue with myDer01 declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
VectorPointers_t myVector;

myVector.push_back(Base_p(new Derived));
```

---

There is a big error in your code: The line declaring `myDer01` actually declares a *function* and not a a variable. But even if you had written `(Derived())` instead of `Derived` it would have been wrong, since you cannot construct a shared pointer from an object — only from a pointer! So you really want to say `new Derived`.

Comment: Is it possible to use `std::make_shared<Derived>()`?

Comment: @Benj: Not in TR1 to my knowledge.

Comment: Ah, yes, if we're to believe the namespace.

Comment: How does the line referred to above define a function?  The line creates a variable and initialises it to the value within the parentheses.  In this case, the value within parentheses is a shared_ptr to a different class.

Comment: @JonTrauntvein: Briefly, in `int exit(int);`, is `exit` a function or a variable? But let's please not derail the topic.

Answer (score -1):

shared_ptr is a class template and each invocation of that template with different parameters will result in a separate class.  The solution is to create only shared pointers to the base class.

Comment: Shared-pointers-to-derived are convertible to shared-pointers-to-base. This is not the problem.

Comment: The standard allows pointers of a derived type to be assigned to a pointer to a base type.  Unless there is a major new language feature that I am not aware of, templates do not follow this rule.  The shared_ptr template is a feature of the C++ standard library and not of the language itself.

Comment: Fortunately, the inventors of the library were smart enough to give the shared pointer similar semantics. They even provide `static_pointer_cast` and `dynamic_pointer_cast` functions to replicate the corresponding behaviour for smart pointers.

Comment: I though `shared_ptr` conversion ctors are explicit. But they aren't except for conversion from `weak_ptr` :-(

Comment: @Rost, the conversion constructors won't compile if the equivalent conversion with built-in pointers isn't implicit, so the behaviour matches built-in pointers, which is usually what you want: "If in doubt, do as the ints do"

Comment: @JonathanWakely I see no problem to explicitly write `base_ptr p = base_ptr(derived_ptr)` instead of implicit `base_ptr p = derived_ptr` when using smart pointers.

Comment: And you are free to do so. I see no problem having implicit conversions when they are provably safe, so I am free to do that, so we're both happy